# Is there list box in TTK like in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I tried to find it with Visual Studio Code, internet but didn't found the answer!
Please answer if TTK has list box.

Comment: No ttk doesn't have Listbox widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, ttk doesn't have a listbox widget. You can use the ttk `Treeview` like a listbox without too much work, however.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(root)
listbox = ttk.Treeview(root, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, show="tree")
scrollbar.configure(command=listbox.yview)

scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
listbox.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

for i in range(100):
    text = f"Item #{i+1}"
    listbox.insert("", "end", text=text)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]